# Calling the real object's method from a shadowed method results in infinite recursion

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, android-testing, robolectric

I created a shadow class that calls into the real object as described in http://robolectric.org/extending:

```
@Implements(View::class)
class MyShadowView {

    @RealObject
    private lateinit var realView: View

    @Implementation
    fun animate(): ViewPropertyAnimator {
        return realView.animate() // this call ends up calling my shadow's animate() function recursively
    }
}
```

However, when my shadow method gets executed, it results in an infinite recursion.

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using Robolectric 4.2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://robolectric.org/javadoc/4.1/org/robolectric/shadow/api/Shadow.html it should be something like this:

```
    @Implementation
    fun animate(): ViewPropertyAnimator {
        Shadow.directlyOn(realView, View::class.java).animate()
    }
```